# SPRING DATA-JPA + eclipseLink2.0 failed

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa

In my test project, Spring container can't create a bean that extends JpaRepository due to following error.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'srSvcInfoMtrRepository': FactoryBean
>   threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   ***java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:***
>   ***javax.persistence.EntityManager.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;***

It might be the problem relevant to JPA version.

I specified certain persistenceProvider in eclipelink2.0(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider) at persistence.xml.

do you have any idea about this problem?

***Stacktrace***

> 2012-05-14 09:11:08 ERROR Caught
>   exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@112da40]
>   to prepare test instance
>   ***> [net.tjjang.learn.spring_jpa.test.SrSvcInfoMtrTest@b6d6ab]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)**
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>    **Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'srSvcInfoMtrRepository': FactoryBean
>   threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;**
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1441)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
>     ... 24 more 
>   **> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.EntityManager.getMetamodel()Ljavax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel;***
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:145)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:146)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:39)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)

***JpaRepository Class()***

```
package net.tjjang.learn.spring_jpa.repositories;
import net.tjjang.learn.spring_jpa.domain.SrSvcInfoMtr;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface SrSvcInfoMtrRepository extends JpaRepository<SrSvcInfoMtr, String> {
    Page<SrSvcInfoMtr> findBySvc_nm(String svc_nm, Pageable pageable);
}
```

***app-context.xml(not all the contents of app-context.xml)***

```
    <!-- for data access -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
    p:driverClassName="cubrid.jdbc.driver.CUBRIDDriver" p:url="jdbc:cubrid:localhost:30000:test:test::" 
    p:username="test" p:password="*******" p:initialSize="5" p:maxActive="10"> 
    </bean -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JpaPersistenceUnit" />
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="net.tjjang.learn.spring_jpa" />
<import resource="infrastructure.xml" />
```

***Persistence.xml***

```
    <persistence-unit name="JpaPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>net.tjjang.learn.spring_jpa.domain.Car</class>
    <class>net.tjjang.learn.spring_jpa.domain.SrSvcInfoMtr</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

***Libraries***

- \org\springframework\spring-aop\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-asm\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-core\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-orm\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-tx\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-aspects\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-aspects-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-expression\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-beans\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-test\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\spring-instrument\3.1.0.RELEASE\spring-instrument-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \junit\junit\4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar
- \org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.0\slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
- \org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.6.0\jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.0.jar
- \org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.6.0\slf4j-log4j12-1.6.0.jar
- \log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar
- \cubrid\cubrid-jdbc\8.4.1.2032\cubrid-jdbc-8.4.1.2032.jar
- \org\eclipse\persistence\eclipselink\2.0.0\eclipselink-2.0.0.jar
- \org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.0.3.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar
- \org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons-core\1.1.0.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
- \org\hibernate\ejb3-persistence\1.0.2.GA\ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
- \org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.8\aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
- \org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.6.11\aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar
- \commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.2.2-p1\commons-dbcp-1.2.2-p1.jar
- \commons-pool\commons-pool\1.4\commons-pool-1.4.jar
- \mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.10\mysql-connector-java-5.1.10.jar

Answer (score 5):

Spring Data JPA requires JPA 2.0. You have pulled the 1.0 version of it into your classpath (the `ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar`, by whatever means). Make sure you use a recent version of EclipseLink that supports JPA 2.0. Version 2.3.2 is the current release version.